# Affinity at container level?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, azure-aks

I have a daemonset which has a Pod, in that pod I wish to have two containers, `a` and `b`. However, I wish to deploy `a` to all nodes, but `b` is only needed to nodes satisfying certain selectors.

`a` and `b` must be in the same pod. So two daemon sets is not an option.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possibile to do what you have in mind because the pod is the basic component of Kubernetes and it is not a divisible component, so you cannot deploy the containers in it on different nodes.

Either you deploy the whole pod to all nodes or on nodes satisfying selectors.